# Cannot find any package

Tags: go

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/TheThingsNetwork/packet_forwarder/blob/master/docs/INSTALL_INSTRUCTIONS/SPI.md), I installed and configured go on my ubuntu 16.04

```
go version
go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64
```

go env output:

```
go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/egmintel/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build216980961=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

but I am stuck with the first instraction:

```
 go get -u github.com/TheThingsNetwork/packet_forwarder
```

I got these errors:

```
$ go get -u github.com/TheThingsNetwork/packet_forwarder
    package github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/gateway: cannot find package "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/gateway" in any of:
            /usr/local/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/gateway (from $GOROOT)
            /home/egmintel/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/gateway (from $GOPATH)
    package github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/discovery: cannot find package "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/discovery" in any of:
            /usr/local/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/discovery (from $GOROOT)
            /home/egmintel/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/discovery (from $GOPATH)
    package github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/fields: cannot find package "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/fields" in any of:
            /usr/local/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/fields (from $GOROOT)
            /home/egmintel/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/fields (from $GOPATH)
    package github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol: cannot find package "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol" in any of:
            /usr/local/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol (from $GOROOT)
            /home/egmintel/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol (from $GOPATH)
    package github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol/lorawan: cannot find package "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol/lorawan" in any of:
            /usr/local/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol/lorawan (from $GOROOT)
            /home/egmintel/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/protocol/lorawan (from $GOPATH)
    package github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/router: cannot find package "github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/router" in any of:
            /usr/local/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/router (from $GOROOT)
            /home/egmintel/go/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/api/router (from $GOPATH)
```

Any ideas what have I missed? Have I miss configured go environment? 
thanks!

Comment: `go env` output?

Comment: also try `go get -v -u github.com/TheThingsNetwork/packet_forwarder`

Comment: There is no `protocol` package in https://github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/tree/develop/api. Referenced in https://github.com/TheThingsNetwork/packet_forwarder/blob/master/pktfwd/uplinks.go. Quite a few references to packages that don't exist.

Comment: @captncraig you found the references in `master`, but tried to resolve them in `develop`. They exist in `master`: https://github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn/tree/master/api

Comment: Hmm, it looks like develop is the default branch in github, and what gets pulled via `go get`.

Comment: Yep, looks like you're right - package maintainer broke it by setting it to default develop.